# Error with jQuery BBQ

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

Bizarre error getting thrown with jQuery BBQ:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>

</head>
</html>
```

Uncaught RefernceError: jQuery is not defined.

The javascript files are in the same directory as the HTML file.

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Is there something I don't know about importing javascript libraries, or is this just a problem with jquery BBQ?

Comment: First load the jQuery then load the jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, imports in jQuery are ordered! Thanks so much, undefined.

You simply need to switch the order of the two javascript references, so that jQuery is imported for jQuery BBQ to use.